# How to use a select menu for user registration in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

My current code:

```
<select ng-model="user.userType" ng-required="true" class="form-control">
   <option value="pharmacist">Pharmacist</option>
   <option value="chief_pharmacist">Chief Pharmacist</option>
   <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>    
</select>

//sample code
```

I need 3 user types to be in the select menu and to pass the selected value to the database.

Comment: What you want to achieve? Its working: http://plnkr.co/edit/YzHPRKUMpnwGPySWJZwg?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an angular controller with your view, like this.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.user = {};
  
  $scope.registerUser = function(){
    alert($scope.user.userType);
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <select ng-model="user.userType" ng-required="true" class="form-control">
                <option value="pharmacist">Pharmacist</option>
                <option value="chief_pharmacist">Chief Pharmacist</option>
                <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>

    </select>
    <button ng-click="registerUser()">register</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, I have listed two ways to achieve this, also have mentioned what value you should pass (I prefer passing `id` rather than `name`):

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YzHPRKUMpnwGPySWJZwg?p=preview)